# why onclick is not working with innerHtml

Tags: javascript

Here I am trying to add html to an element using innerHtml

```
  <body>
 <h3>Dynamically Retrieve the chapter name</h3>
<div>
<div>
    <button id="addChapter">Add Chapter</button>
    <div id="courseStructure">

    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var addChapter = document.getElementById("addChapter");

  addChapter.onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("courseStructure").innerHtml += '<div><input type="text" name="chaptername" placeholder="chapter name"/><button id="addSubChapter">Add SubChapter</button><button id="addContent">Add Content</button><br><br></div>';
 }
```

everything seems good the onclick event is firing when button is clicked but the html is not getting added to the element.

Comment: Its `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`

Comment: @Satpal thank you. You just saved me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not written innerHTML in proper format. its innerHTML instead of innerHtml
your code should be..

```
<body>
<h3>Dynamically Retrieve the chapter name</h3>
<div>
<div>
<button id="addChapter">Add Chapter</button>
<div id="courseStructure">

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Your .JS file will be.

```
var addChapter = document.getElementById("addChapter");

addChapter.onclick = function()
{
document.getElementById("courseStructure").innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="chaptername" placeholder="chapter name"/>
<button id="addSubChapter">Add SubChapter</button>
<button id="addContent">Add Content</button>
<br><br></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `innerHtml` to `innerHTML`.

```js
var addChapter = document.getElementById("addChapter");

  addChapter.onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("courseStructure").innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="chaptername" placeholder="chapter name"/><button id="addSubChapter">Add SubChapter</button><button id="addContent">Add Content</button><br><br></div>';
 }
```

```html
<h3>Dynamically Retrieve the chapter name</h3>
<div>
<div>
    <button id="addChapter">Add Chapter</button>
    <div id="courseStructure">

    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can selecting on js:

```
$("#courseStructure").click(function(){
document.getElementById("courseStructure").innerHtml += '<div><input type="text" name="chaptername" placeholder="chapter name"/><button id="addSubChapter">Add SubChapter</button><button id="addContent">Add Content</button><br><br></div>';
});
```

or:

```
<button id="addChapter" onclick="myFunction()">Add Chapter</button>
```